# How to create a SASS rule like "apply to element if parent is not x"

Tags: html, css, sass, parent

First of all, I'm sorry if there is already a similar question that I ask, but it is not that easy to search for that specific case.

**What I want to achieve, is coloring every "a" element, except those that are wrapped in a header element h1,h2,h3,h4,h5.**

I'm aware of the parent selector, but I don't want to apply anything to the parent, but the child element I create the CSS rule for.

What I came up with so far was this:

```
a {

    & {
      background-color: yellow;
    }

    &:not(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6) {

      @apply text-blue-600 break-words;

      & :hover {
        @apply text-blue-700;
      }
    }
  }
```

It seems to have no effect and applies the style to all "a" tags still, and the yellow background is applied to the "a" tag as well, which is the **current element**, not to the **parent element**, which is opposing to what I understood from the docs.

**How do I create a correct selector based on what the parent of my "a" element is?**

Comment: nothing SASS can do. It would require a parent selector. The currently available parent selector is `:has()` which is only supported by chromium browser version 105 (Chrome: 30th August 22, Edge: 1st September 22), Safri at 15.4 (14th March 22) and by Firefox with Beta-Developer Tools activated since version 103 (26th July 22). So it is not ready for productive use.

Comment: @tacoshy thanks, good to know. So I guess one solution would be setting a global default and declaring overwrites for specific elements, such as h tags

Answer (score 1):

```
a:not(h1>a, h2>a, h3>a){
  background-color: yellow;
  
  &:not(h1, h2, h3){
    color: DarkBlue;
    &:hover {
        color: blue;
      }
  }
}
```

My limited testing shows this scss does what I think you're aiming for.
[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/24ptnfca/1/)
You'd have to edit it to include all headers and your own colours